# Complex JQuery selector - how to select one arbitrary 'generation'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, children

We're using a framework which creates arbitrarily nested HTML data elements identified by the attribute `data-type=[some data type]`.  Each of these can contain direct input fields as well as other `data-type`, either as singletons or arrays.  The only saving grace of the nesting structure is a `data-type` will never contain `data-types` of the same type at any depth.

**The HTML I *have to* work with**

```
<div data-type='project' id='example1'>
  <input name='start-date'/>
  <div data-type='project-lead' id='example2'>
    <input name='department'/>
    <input name='email'/>
    <div data-type='analyst'>      
      <input name='department'/>
      <input name='email'/>
    </div>
    <div data-type='analyst'>      
      <input name='department'/>
      <input name='email'/>
    </div>
    <div data-type='analyst'>      
      <input name='department'/>
      <input name='email'/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="JustToMakeMyLifeMoreDifficult">
    <div data-type='sponsor'>      
      <input name='department'/>
      <input name='email'/>
    </div>
    <div data-type='sponsor'>      
      <input name='department'/>
      <input name='email'/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The Selector Problem**

I need a JQuery find selector which gets me the set of `data-type` elements one `data-type` level beneath the given object:

```
myData($obj){
  return $obj.find('[data-type]').not([data-type elements further down]);
}
```

Such that:

```
myData($('#example1'))
myData($('#example2'))
```

respectively yields jquery results:

```
[project-lead,sponsor,sponsor]
[analyst, analyst, analyst]
```

JQuery wizards, please help me.  You're the only the ones that can.

**Answered**

This isn't possible with JQuery selectors.  I wrapped Patrick's very elegant solution below into a generalized JQuery function-

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.dataChildren = function(_selector) {
        var iter = this;
        var res = this.children(_selector);
        while ( ( iter = iter.children(':not(' + _selector +')') ).length ) {
                res = res.add(iter.children(_selector));
        }
        return res;
  };
})( jQuery );
```

So that:

```
$('#example1').dataChildren('[data-type]')
```

Works as described above. I <3 SO.

Comment: It seems to me that you want the div childNodes that have a *data-* attribute, and for those that don't have one, get the div childNodes that do. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2:** I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var el = $('#example1');

var res = el.children('[data-type]');

while ( ( el = el.children(':not([data-type])') ).length ) {
    res = res.add(el.children('[data-type]'));
}
```

This one goes recursively deep, but the recursion on any child branch stops when an element is found *with* `data-type`, so it only continues as long as there's a child that does *not* have `data-type`.

*It may be easier to follow if I use a `do-while` loop, and unwind some of the code:*

```
var el = $('#example1');  // el is the current level
var res = $();            // res holds the result
var data_types;           // holds the children with data-type for the current level

do {
      // from current level, get children with data-type
    data_types = el.children('[data-type]'); 

      // add those to the result set
    res = res.add( data_types );

      // make the current level be the children of the current level that
      //      do NOT have data-type
    el = el.children().not( data_types );

} while( el.length ); // continue as long as the new current level
                      //     has at least one element
```

> .
>
> .

<s>**EDIT:** *I may have misunderstood one part.*</s>

It looks like an element with `data-type` may have children that also have `data-type`. If that's the case, change the selector to this:

```
var ex = $('#example1');

var res = ex.find('> [data-type], > * > [data-type]');
```

So to sum this one up, it says get all *children* and *grandchildren* that have a `data-type` attribute.

---

**Original answer:**

If I understand you want children with `data-type`, and of the children that are not `data-type`, you need too add their children that are `data-type`.

```
var ex = $('#example1');

var res = ex.find('> [data-type], > :not([data-type]) > [data-type]');
```

This uses the [`multiple-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

The first selector is:

```
'> [data-type]'
```

...which will get children that have a `data-type` attribute.

The second selector is:

```
'> :not([data-type]) > [data-type]'
```

...which will first get children that do *not* have `data-type`, but of those, it will get their children that *do* have `data-type`.

Does that look like what you want?

Comment: This looks like it might be on the right track, but I don't think it handles example2 right now.  Can you break down what's going on in the second half of that selector?

Comment: @RSG: Which one are you talking about. My "original answer" or the "edit". Looking at it again, the "original answer" does meet the example output, but I wasn't sure if it met your description.

Comment: I was talking about the original answer, our posts crossed. :) The update is helpful, but if I read it right it's hardcoded to find datatype children at two DOM levels.  IRL there are many more JustToMakeMyLifeMoreDifficult divs- I'd have to write n versions of the > * > selector, right?

Comment: @RSG: Ok, I was confused because with the current example HTML, the original answer gives me the correct solution (as compared to your example output). But if you're saying that you need to recursively go deep, always looking for `data-type` elements that do *not* descend from another `data-type` element, then it will take some adjustment. Does it sound like I have your requirements met correctly?

Comment: Yes. To rephrase: it recursively searches until it finds the data-type tag, then stops searching that branch.  looking at that sentence, this seems like it probably can't be done reasonably with selectors.

Comment: @RSG: I just updated with a recursive search using a `while` loop. At the current level, it gets children with `data-type`. Then it makes the new "current level" the children *without* `data-type`, and adds children of that level that do have `data-type` to the result... and repeats recursively until there are no more children that do not have `data-type`.

Comment: Thanks for the multiple revisions- this was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A POJS function that does what you want and returns an array of the matched element is:

```
function getNodes(id) {
  var el = (typeof id == 'string')? document.getElementById(id) : id;
  var result = [];
  var node, nodes = el.childNodes;
  var prop = 'data-type';
  var tag = 'div';

  for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    node = nodes[i];

    if (node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == tag) {

      if (node.getAttribute(prop)) {
        result.push(node);

      } else {
        result = result.concat(getNodes(node));
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

However, I'm not sure you want it to go as deep as this one might. It can be modified to only go to a certain depth (say one or two levels).

Comment: Arbitrary depth is a requirement, I'll probably have to use something similar if jquery has nothing suitable.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$obj.find('> [data-type]');
```

should work if I get your problem right.

Selector `'> [data-type]'` means "give me all elements having 'data-type' defined and that are immediate children of the container.

Comment: Thanks, but there are arbitrary markup divs (as in the example) that make this not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj.children().map(function () {return this.name;})
```

perhaps?